# How to draw three y axis using the gnuplot at the same x axis in one graph?

Tags: plot, gnuplot

As mentioned in my title, I need to draw more than two y axis for the same x-axis  of some specific scale. Can someone can tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 6):

In gnuplot only two differently scaled y-axis are possible.
But you could either

- scale your data against a certain value to plot relative values instead of absolute values,
- or simply have multiple plots. ([multiplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.2/gnuplot.html#x1-20500043.38))

Comment: Thanks your answer,I have depose it with the multiple plots.However,I found the result is not better. Now attach my test scirpt like this:</br>reset</br>
set multiplot</br>
set origin 0,0</br>
set key box </br>
set size 1,1</br>
set xrange [-pi:pi]</br>

set yrange [-2:2]</br>
set key box at pi,2</br>
plot sin(x)  lc rgb "red" lw 2</br>

unset xtics</br>
set ytics nomirror
</br>
set border 2 lc 3 lw 2</br>
set origin 0.018,0</br>
set size 1-0.018,1</br>
set yrange [-1:1]</br>
set key box at pi,1-0.1</br>
plot cos(x) lc rgb "green" lw 2</br>